# how to use events in react html parser

Tags: html, reactjs

`getrow` is my function where I create a dynamic input box. I want to receive `onchange` events for every input box. I am using `ReactHtmlParse` but it's not allowed to do this. Is there any other way to do?

```
 getRow = (row, column) => {
input_fields = '';
input_fields+='<table><tbody>'
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.dataObj[column.dataIndex])) {
  console.log(key)
  input_fields += '<tr><td>' + key + ':<br>' + '<input class="edit_fields" type="text" id='
   + key  + '>'+ '</td></tr>'
}
input_fields+='</tbody></table>'
row_data =input_fields
this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true }); }
 
              <LVModal
              width={240}
              height={350}
              title="Update Value"
              onClose={this.closeModal}
              closeOnOverlayClick
              isMovable
              isResizable
              closeOnEsc
            >
              {ReactHtmlParser(row_data)}
              <LVButton>Save</LVButton>
            </LVModal>
```

Comment: getRow = (row, column) => {
    input_fields = '';
    input_fields+='<table><tbody>'
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.state.dataObj[column.dataIndex])) {
      console.log(key)
      input_fields += '<tr><td>' + key + ':<br>' + '<input class="edit_fields" type="text" id='
       + key + ' value=' +  value + `onClick=+this.inputChangedHandler` +'/>'+ '</td></tr>'
    }
    input_fields+='</tbody></table>'
    row_data =input_fields
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
  }

Comment: above is my correct function

Comment: you need to pass onClick parameter to getRow(row, column, onClick) and  onClick={onClick()}

Comment: @Sodhi when am passing   '<input class="edit_fields" type="text" id='
       + key  + onClick={onClick()}'>'  it is saying ....  (parameter) onClick: any
';' expected.ts(1005)

Comment: can u brief me like how can i pass events inside input box

Comment: could you please create https://codesandbox.io/ for it, I will have a look later

Answer (score 0):

this is my way to solve similar issues.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import parse from "html-react-parser";

const html = `
  <div style="font-size:32px;">html-react-parser with js events</div>
  <div>This is a long long long text.<div id="supportEmail"></div>t is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</div>
`;

const handlefunction = () => {
  alert("Clicked");
};

const replace = (domNode) => {
  if (domNode.attribs && domNode.attribs.id === "supportEmail") {
    return (
      <code>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "gray",
            padding: "4px 8px",
            width: "100px",
            textAlign: "center"
          }}
          onClick={handlefunction}
        >
          Click
        </div>
      </code>
    );
  }
};

function App() {
  return parse(html, { replace });
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Check example in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-parm-zsbn2n?file=/src/index.js:0-1155)